# можно ли подключить сервис к двум модулям

Tags: angularjs

Есть проект с 2 отдельными модулями, `.module('app')`и `.module('secondApp')`. В модуле `.module('app')` у меня есть сервис, для валидации полей, сейчас возникла необходимость данный сервис добавить и к `.module('secondApp')`. Можно ли его подключить к 2 модулям, чтобы не делать копию сервиса, а использовать имеющийся?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вынести сервис в отдельный модуль, подключить этот модуль в зависимости к двум другим, а затем пользоваться сервисом из него.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('MainApp', ['app', 'secondApp']);
```